# IIS Redirect - axd files getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, webresource.axd

The rewrite rule i built returns **500 Internal Server Error** for path that contains **axd**.
all other paths works fine.

the rule:

```
<rule name="isite rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
     <match url="sub.*" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{MY_INTERNAL_SERVER}:8383/{R:0}"/>
</rule>
```

everything work's fine but url's that contains **axd** path fails with **500 Internal Server Error**

for example:
http://sub.site.com/WebResource.axd?d=VulAtfIQPaLvaSxP9LTeiyvvAmd8FbIf6Q9ixGIpCgSDhZqzJbeu9udOTMbvs9iVhh4fHt3IYOe_Kp2xsAxYVpD0efUoQhQMVWmavqplBDk1&t=636445915058816667

Comment: The rule you created won't even touch the URL you pasted. Learn how to debug first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis or others might downvote you, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: the rule is working!.. except axd path as i mentioned which i am getting net::ERR_ABORTED for them.